# determine which predefined graphical region a user is in using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

using mongo, I would like to compare a user's geo coordinates to a collection of documents each representing a defined geographical boundary. This is what i have thought to do, but cant get working. Other suggestions to get the same result are also welcome.
A document from the collection looks like this (those are manhattan coordinates, if you draw a line in sequence from one coordinate to the next, it wraps manhattan)

```
{
    "__v" : 1,
      "_id" : ObjectId("53220803a74a16da9c729202"),
    "name" : "Manhattan",
    "boundary" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            [ 
                [ 
                    -74.01237999999999, 
                    40.69967
                ], 
                [ 
                    -73.97895, 
                    40.71076
                ], 
                [ 
                    -73.97169, 
                    40.73049
                ], 
                [ 
                    -73.92828, 
                    40.79605
                ], 
                [ 
                    -73.95547999999999, 
                    40.82635
                ], 
                [ 
                    -74.00901, 
                    40.75431
                ], 
                [ 
                    -74.01961, 
                    40.7059
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

i then use the following query to make my check

```
 db.collection.find( { boundary :
                     { $geoIntersects :
                        { $geometry :
                           { type : "Point" ,
                             coordinates : [ [user_long, user_lat] ]
                  } } } } ).exec(function(err, city){
            console.log(err, "error");
            res.send({agent_count : city});
          });
```

Comment: For starters, you could not have indexed this with a "2d" or "2dsphere"  index as the geometry is invalid. Your last point in the "Polygon" needs to be the same as the first. And you need to "index" your field before your query can work.

Comment: my field is indexed. i just didn't put that in here. Let me check the geometry.

Comment: and the fixed geometry doesnt help it. Any other ideas?

Comment: What are your point co-ordinates in the query? You are just showing variables and not values. For a "Point" geometry it actually needs to be within on intersecting with a line point of the polygon to match.

Comment: They are lattitude and longitude

Comment: Um, The actual coordinates? No one here can see if they would actually be within the bounds of the Polygon you are trying to match.